# how to remove menu items (file, edit, view, format) from the text editor and Character Limit validation for TinyMCE editor using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

how to remove menu items (file, edit, view, format) from the text editor and  Character Limit validation for TinyMCE editor using JavaScript and i am following this example:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Character-Count-and-Character-Limit-validation-for-TinyMCE-editor-using-JavaScript.aspx

```
 <div>
 <textarea id="txtTinyMCE" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
 <br />
 <div id="character_count">
 </div>
 <br />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return ValidateCharacterLength();" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
</div>
```

Java Script code for restricting maximum characters:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        width: 400,
        setup: function (ed) {
            ed.on('keyup', function (e) {
                var count = CountCharacters();
                document.getElementById("character_count").innerHTML = "Characters: " + count;
            });
        }
    });
}
function CountCharacters() {
    var body = tinymce.get("txtTinyMCE").getBody();
    var content = tinymce.trim(body.innerText || body.textContent);
    return content.length;
};
function ValidateCharacterLength() {
    var max = 3000;
    var count = CountCharacters();
    if (count > max) {
        alert("Maximum " + max + " characters allowed.")
        return false;
    }
    return;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation for [the TinyMCE menubar](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:menubar) it looks like you can configure what is displayed in the setup. In your case, you would add your configurations in your window.onload function.

ie

```
tinymce.init({
    menu : { // this is the complete default configuration
        file   : {title : 'File'  , items : 'newdocument'},
        edit   : {title : 'Edit'  , items : 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall'},
        insert : {title : 'Insert', items : 'link media | template hr'},
        view   : {title : 'View'  , items : 'visualaid'},
        format : {title : 'Format', items : 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat'},
        table  : {title : 'Table' , items : 'inserttable tableprops deletetable | cell row column'},
        tools  : {title : 'Tools' , items : 'spellchecker code'}
    }
});
```

From what I can see, i'd assume to hide an item, you would just need to set it to false.

Comment: Yeah, I did false to the menu bar using  menubar: false. But I want also disable to formats and undo, reundo marks.

Comment: Did you have a look at the [toolbar config](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:toolbar), is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah, but i am not unable to disable these formats and undo, reundo marks. Already disable file,view,edit and format. Just need to disable formats and undo, reundo. i have to keep these menus only (Bold, italic and page arrangement menus). @theatlasroom.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle example? I can't really give more advice without playing around. I'd assume you could just set undo etc to false like the other options. Or perhaps hide it by css